# Rails 4 - getting no method error while using has_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an action like this

```
def fetch
    @result = LinkThumbnailer.generate(params[:url], strict: false, limit: 1)
    if @result.has_key?('image')
      @result[:thumbnail_url] = @result.image
    elsif @result.has_key?('images')
      @result[:thumbnail_url] = @result.images.first
    else
      @result[:thumbnail_url] = ""
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @result }
    end
  end
```

But i'm getting this error

```
NoMethodError at /bookmarks/new/fetch undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClassapp/controllers/bookmarks_controller.rb
```

But I tried this in IRB like this

```
2.1.0 :015 > object = LinkThumbnailer.generate('http://dribbble.com/shots/1455760-ID-Card?list=popular&offset=3',strict: false, limit:1)
 => #<LinkThumbnailer::Object description=" Inspired by zee7,AH,Hope you guys like it!" image="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/219089/screenshots/1455760/user_thumbnail.png" images=["https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/219089/screenshots/1455760/user_thumbnail.png"] site_name="Dribbble" title="ID Card" type="article" url="http://dribbble.com/shots/1455760-ID-Card"> 
2.1.0 :016 > object.has_key?('image')
 => true
```

`has_key` works fine in irb. can someone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@result` value is nil. That is why you are getting error.

See if params[:url] is equal to `http://dribbble.com/shots/1455760-ID-Card?list=popular&offset=3`.

Make sure that `LinkThumbnailer.generate(params[:url], strict: false, limit: 1)` returns a value and not nil.

```
def fetch
    puts params[:url] ## Check params[:url] value on console
    @result = LinkThumbnailer.generate(params[:url], strict: false, limit: 1)
    unless @result.nil? ## Check if @result is nil
      if @result.has_key?('image')
        @result[:thumbnail_url] = @result.image
      elsif @result.has_key?('images')
        @result[:thumbnail_url] = @result.images.first
      else
        @result[:thumbnail_url] = ""
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @result }
      end
     end
  end
```

Comment: Yep.. You are right. @result has nil value. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer when timeout is over :)

Comment: Looks like I need to wait 5 more minutes to accept your answer. Will do it. Don't worry. Take care